# tf.keras.Model.save throws Not JSON Serializable when dtype of Input is uint8

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

TensorFlow: 1.14.0

I am trying to modify the MobileNetV2 implementation from tf.keras.applications to accept a uint8 input rather than float32. I then add the cast to float32 and rescaling to [-1,1] as the first few layers of the model. The idea is to have the conversion be part of the inference  graph rather than having to do it outside of TF.

To that end, here are the lines with the relevant changes in mobilenet_v2.py:

```
if input_tensor is None:
    img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, dtype="uint8")
...
x = backend.cast(img_input, dtype="float32")
x *= 1 / 127.5
x -= 1.0

first_block_filters = _make_divisible(32 * alpha, 8)
x = layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=correct_pad(backend, x, 3),
                         name='Conv1_pad')(x)
...
```

model.fit runs without issues, but when I try to save the model with model.save it throws

```
model.save(path.join(best_model_dir, "model.h5"))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1211, in save
  saving.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 113, in save_model
model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 101, in save_model_to_hdf5
default=serialization.get_json_type).encode('utf8')
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/serialization.py", line 69, in get_json_type
raise TypeError('Not JSON Serializable:', obj)
TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', b'\n\x04Cast\x12\x04Cast\x1a\x07input_1*\n\n\x04SrcT\x12\x020\x04*\x0e\n\x08Truncate\x12\x02(\x00*\n\n\x04DstT\x12\x020\x01')
```

I have also tried to create my own keras InputLayer followed by the cast and rescale and replaced the input layer of the unmodified MobileNetV2 model with it, but I ended up with the same exception.

[edit]
Here is the code for my alternative approach, which is really the cleaner way to do it I suppose. The error remains the same, though.

```
images = layers.Input(shape=(56, 112, 3), dtype="uint8", name="input")
x = tf.keras.backend.cast(images, dtype="float32")
x *= 1 / 127.5
x -= 1.0

# Prepare the model trunk.
mobilenet = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(56, 112, 3), include_top=False,
                                              weights="imagenet")
mobilenet.layers.pop(0)
x = mobilenet(x)

... add output layers ...

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=images, outputs=outputs)
```

[/edit]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Serialization seems to fail as soon as I change the dtype of the Input to anything other than float32.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.numpy()` function for `tf.Variable` methods when feeding into loss functions or other relevant places.

This might work for ex:
`x = backend.cast(img_input, dtype="float32").numpy()`

I was encountering a similar problem when changing from `TensorFlow: 1.4` code to `TensorFlow: 2.1.0` and `.numpy()` resolved the issue.
Sample code that I used for my similar issue is as follows:

> alpha = K.variable(value=0.98, dtype="float32", name="alpha")
> ...
> loss_weights=[alpha.numpy()]         # added .numpy()

Please refer here for more details on the solution:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28799#issuecomment-739474591

Answer (score 0):

Go to: \tensorflow\python\keras_impl\keras\models.py

Change return int(obj) to return int(obj.value or 0)

```
# ... earlier get_json_type code
# NOTE: Hacky fix to serialize Dimension objects.
from tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape import Dimension
if type(obj) == Dimension:
  **return int(obj.value or 0)**
# original error raised here
raise TypeError('Not JSON Serializable:', obj)
```

[Keras Save Model Not JSON Serializable](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9342)

> When you specify dtype, can you use either the tensorflow types, or a string. To save the model, you should use a string. Please see https://keras.io/layers/core/#input .

[Save model TypeError](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11110)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This doesn't seem to work for me, though. I am already using strings for the dtypes in the Keras model as shown in the code snippets. I also don't have the file you referred to, the get_json_type function which causes the error is in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/serialization.py for me and has   ```if isinstance(obj, tensor_shape.Dimension):
    return obj.value
``` for the comparison with Dimension. I tried casting the returned value to int, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Given that the error is raised at the end of the function, none of the if conditions actually evaluates to True, so it's not a problem with the returned type.

Answer (score 0):

The model could be turned into serializable by wrapping the "cast" and the arithmetic operations with "layers.Lambda()".  More specifically, replace this:

```
images = layers.Input(shape=(56, 112, 3), dtype="uint8", name="input")
x = tf.keras.backend.cast(images, dtype="float32")
x *= 1 / 127.5
x -= 1.0
```

with:

```
images = layers.Input(shape=(56, 112, 3), dtype="uint8", name="input")
x = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.backend.cast(x, dtype="float32"))(images)
x = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * (1/127.5) - 1.0)(x)
```